# My book has a similar characters as the book The One and Only Ivan. Will I get in trouble if I publish my book?

Tags: characters, publishing, copyright

We have completely different plots, I have several characters that are similar but different to each other. The One and Only Ivan had a gorilla, elephant, and dog, while I have a chimpanzee, elephant, and dog. The chimpanzee is different from the gorilla, however, the two elephants are similar. They have different intentions, but the traits are similar. Both elephants are curious. Both of them are away from their real home. The biggest difference is that the character from the One and Only Ruby is not shy, while mine is. Both dogs are completely different. Although I've added several tweaks to the characters, I'm afraid that they might be too similar. Will I get in trouble if I publish my book?

Comment: Hi Alexandra, welcome to writing.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. I've closed your question as it is very similar to one we've had before. That's ok! Duplicates can help other users find the answers they need easier. However if you don't feel that question answers yours, you can [edit] your post to clarify how it is different and flag your question to get reopened. Good luck and happy writing!

Answer (score 3):

> Both Ellie and Ruby are curious. Both of them are away from their real home.

In all honesty, if those are the only traits they have in common, then it's unlikely that anyone is going to notice any similarity at all. Certainly, this isn't anywhere near enough for you to get in any sort of trouble if you were to publish your book.

If your protagonist was also called Ruby, and your story's plot was noticeably similar to that of "The One and Only Ivan", then that would be a different matter, but from your description, these books have so little in common that there's no possible way you could be accused of plagiarising it.

Comment: Hey @F1Krazy, thanks for the immediate response. I just happened to found three other characters that are somewhat similar to The One and Only Ivan. In the One and Only Ivan, there a gorilla(Ivan), an elephant(Ruby), and a dog. The problem is, I just happened to have a chimpanzee AND a dog. They all have different traits that are unique, but I think that the species are a little bit too alike. The chimpanzee and dog characters are very different from each other. I may just be getting worried, but will I get in trouble if I include these characters as well?

Comment: You should edit that information into the question, along with any other similarities you think your story may have with *The One and Only Ivan*. It's generally considered unfair to move the goalposts after a question's already been answered, but I think it would also be unfair of me to just ignore your clarifications and leave an answer that's only partially helpful to you.